# Accidentally filled /dev/sd* with 16000 bytes from /dev/zero, using dd command

Tags: dd

This is the command that I ran in a `sudo`ed terminal:
`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sd* bs=512 count=32`

These are the `sd*` using lsblk:

```
sda      8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk   
├─sda1   8:1    0   600M  0 part /boot/efi  
├─sda2   8:2    0     3G  0 part   
├─sda3   8:3    0 227.2G  0 part /  
└─sda4   8:4    0   7.8G  0 part [SWAP]  
sdb      8:16   1  29.5G  0 disk   
└─sdb1   8:17   1  29.5G  0 part /media/adminn/STRONTIUM
```

I have not restarted the system yet.
Is there a way I can recover the lost/corrupted data?

Comment: Edit question to show output of `ls -l /dev/sd*`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have not restarted the system yet. Is there a way I can recover the lost/corrupted data?

I doubt that you have lost any data. It looks like you got lucky.
Do `ls -l /dev/sd*` to see what you did. There should be a file there that you did not expect.

Comment: OMG thx!!  
gorgeous file :
```
 "-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 16384 May  4 16:30 '/dev/sd*'"  
and the rest   
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  0 May  4 17:25  /dev/sda  
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  1 May  4 17:25  /dev/sda1  
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  2 May  4 17:25  /dev/sda2  
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  3 May  4 17:25  /dev/sda3  
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  4 May  4 17:25  /dev/sda4  
```


How can i remove this sd* thing?
If I had run of=/dev/sda instead, it would have had ruined the data right?
how to recover in this case?

Comment: To delete it you need to quote: `rm '/dev/sd*'` so it does not expand the `*`. Practice before using `sudo`.

Comment: If it destroyed you data, then the recovery procedure is to re-install, and recover user-data from backup / remote-revision-control.

Comment: Worked beatifully!
Thanks a lot for quick and correct reply.

I hope you wouldn't mind if I ask you about what could we have done, if 16 bytes of data from all sda's were remove instead?

Comment: Yup, the shell wouldn’t expand `of=/dev/sd*` (it wouldn’t match anything in most cases).

Comment: @Kartikagarwal your command wouldn't have written _16 bytes of data_ as your [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/584402/accidentally-filled-dev-sd-with-16000-bytes-from-dev-zero-using-dd-command#comment1088225_584406) suggests; it would have written 16 blocks of 512 bytes, i.e. 8 KiB data.

Comment: I don't quite understand why the wildcard `of=/dev/sd*` wouldn't be expanded? Is it because of the `of=` in front?

Comment: @Panki more precisely, it would be expanded, but it typically wouldn’t match anything (unless you happen to have an `of=` directory in the current directory, itself containing a `dev` directory, containing entries starting with `sd`), so the shell would either leave it as-is, remove entirely, or fail, depending on your glob settings.

Comment: @Kartikagarwal if you found the answer useful, please consider accepting it (by clicking on the as-of-yet greyed-out checkmark below the vote counter on the left side) so that others looking for a similar answer may find it more easily.